# конфигурация webpack 1 для bundle.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, config

Не понимаю, каким образом сконфигурировать вебпак для своего проекта. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрел многочисленные гайды, но я не понимаю что в конце концов требуется, чтобы просто собрать все файлы `js` и привести их в один `bundle.js`.

Я бы привел код наработок - но это бессмысленно, потому что кроме entry и output больше ничего не понял.

Буду благодарен за минимальный конфиг с пояснениями, что зачем и куда, просто чтобы собрать все файлы `js` в один бандл.

Возможно это 2й вебпак, не уверен, но думаю - всё таки что первый. На всякий случай приведу зависимость:

```
"dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для первоначального понимания могу посоветовать вот эти видео, довольно просто объясняется - https://monsterlessons.com/project/series/sborshik-modulej-webpack
https://monsterlessons.com/project/lessons/webpack-2-ustanovka-i-nastrojka

Для большего понимания, конечно придется почитать документацию. Ну и ниже мой минимальный конфиг, для сборки. Надеюсь это поможет и внесет некую ясность) То что тебе сейчас не потребуется (например, сборка css), можешь просто удалить, или закомментить.

```js
//плагин для сборки css файлов в единый, хотя может собирать и в
//разные, зависит от задачи, тут подключение, настройка ниже.

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

//теперь экспортируем объект с настройками

module.exports = {

//тут у нас точка входа для js и прочих файлов, например style - 
//это css. Чтобы собрать все в единый файл, тебе нужно подключить
//все разрозненые js к точке входа, тоесть все твои js файлы
//должны быть импорированы в index.js
//webpack позволяет собирать и разные js-файлы, тогда будет вот 
//такая запись:
/*
entry: {
        bundle1: './app/index1', //путь к файлу.
        bundle2: './app/index2'
    },
*/

    entry: {
        bundle: './app/index', //путь к файлу.
        style: './app/css/style'
    },

//это выход
    output: {
//куда сохраняем js, сейчас в корневом каталоге
        path: __dirname,
//корректное обновление ссылок в файлах при билде
        publicPath: '/',
//название файла, можно задать руками, можно генерить по имени
//точки входа, как сейчас
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    //если кратко, то это позволяет указать, какие типы файлов
    //искать в точке входа (less, sass и т.д.)
    //Важный момент - первый параметр не должен быть пустым!
    //Как видишь, у меня стоит в нем пробел.

    resolve: {
        extensions: [' ', '.js', '.css']
    },

//теперь задаем правила нашей сборки
    module: {
        rules: [
  //пишешь на es6? значит нужен пакет babel, ниже его настройка
            {
  //указываем, какой тип файлов нужно искать для сборки
                test: /\.js$/,
  //исключая какие папки
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
  //использование загрузчиков с пресетами
  //значит, кроме babel, нужно установить пакет пресетов
  //babel-preset-es2015
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
                }]
            },

    //тоже самое, только с css, по настройкам там все просто,
    //посмотри инфу по ExtractTextPlugin и css-loader
            {
                test:   /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: { loader: 'style-loader' },
                        use: {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                import: true,
                                url: true
                            }
                        }
                    })
            },
            
     //тут настраиваем file-loader, чтобы при сборке все картинки
  //и шрифты сохранялись в нужные нам папки с правильными ссылками
            {
                test:   /\.(svg|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&publicPath=&outputPath=../css/fount/'
            },
            {
                test:   /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&publicPath=&outputPath=../css/img/'
            }
        ]
    },

//говорим webpack, что подключили внешний плагин, плюс некоторые
//ручные настройки, которые врядли тебе сейчас понадобятся.
//В документации все подробно описано.
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            allChunks: true})
    ]
};
```